# How to delete multiple lines with different text in between using RegEx in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

What I need to do is to delete everything that ends with `desktop.ini` and begins with `Library` with varying text in between.

In my list, it looks like this:

```
Library\aaaa\desktop.ini
Library\bbbb\1111\desktop.ini
Library\bbbb\line-I-dont-want-to-delete
Library\cccc\222\CCCC\desktop.ini
Library\dddd\3333\D\desktop.ini
```

After using the Replace feature, all that should be left is:

`Library\bbbb\line-I dont-want-to-delete`.

I'm really terrible with RegEx, but what I need is something like this:

`^Library\$[(A-Z)?]\desktop.ini`

Apologies if that's all I have, but thanks in advance for helping me with this!

Comment: A shortest possible code can be `^lib.*ini\n` so that you not forget it soon next time ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Find What:    ^Library\\(?:.*\\)?desktop\.ini$\R?
Replace With: <empty>
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `Library\\` - `Library\` string
- `(?:.*\\)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `\` char
- `desktop\.ini` - a `desktop.ini` string
- `$` - end of line
- `\R?` - an optional line break char (sequence).

See the demo below:

[image]